# Mercurial update seems to overwrite local file

Tags: mercurial

I've been trying to get a grasp on working with Mercurial to keep track of changes made to my local Galaxy instance. I have a test server (local laptop) and a development server (cluster) to test stuff out on before I put in into production. I started out by pushing from dev to a bitbucket repo, and pulling from bitbucket to my test server. Now I'm trying to get stuff to go the other direction.
I've pushed from test to bb using the Eclipse Mercurial plugin. Now I try the following from dev:

```
hg pull
hg update
hg resolve --all
emacs .hgignore
hg resolve -m .hgignore
hg commit -m 'Helpful and informative message'
```

I'm thinking that this will merge the changes I've made on test with my current working directory on the dev server. I start to work from the dev side but it becomes apparent that some of the files that on dev were completely overwritten by the update. I panicked and tried to get out of it:

```
hg heads
hg rollback
hg incoming
hg heads
hg status
hg incoming
hg pull
```

I don't really know what to do in this case because I don't want to strip or backout of the pull in such a way that it will be recorded or remove all of the hard work I did on the test server when I push from dev to bb. I try pulling again:

```
hg update -C bf3924ee142c
#Revert to a clean copy of my last working code
146 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
less job_conf.xml
#This is my most recent local copy and it looks correct
hg merge 6dc34fa         
abort: nothing to merge (use 'hg update' or check 'hg heads')
hg update 6dc34fa
201 files updated, 0 files merged, 15 files removed, 0 files unresolved
less job_conf.xml
#Entirely replaced by the remote copy
```

It reproduces the same behavior, where my local copy is totally lost. I tried removing the file from being tracked on my test server and pushed to bb, then pulled to dev, but the file gets completely deleted in dev.
This job_conf.xml file has to be set up differently each time the software is installed, so I changed the file when I set it up on my test server. I may have deleted it and then copied it from the job_conf.xml.sample file (renamed it to be job_conf.xml) -- I'm not sure if that would screw things up.

I'd appreciate any suggestions/enlightenment on this behavior!

Comment: I noticed you don't have an `hg merge` in your first section of commands.  Is this cut-and-paste error?  What's the output of `hg heads` after the `hg pull`?  You should have two heads (at least) at this point.  What is `6dc34fa`?  It doesn't appear to be a separate head based on the output above.

Comment: Not a typo - I didn't do a merge then (I think it said to update after I pulled). I don't remember what the output of hg heads was then, but right now it only looks like I have one. 6dc34fa is the changeset that is right before the tip on the BB - before I removed the files from being tracked.

Comment: Did you have any files modified when you do the pull?  I don't why your doing the `hg resolve` commands.  Typically you only do that when you have conflicts on a merge.

Comment: Indeed, I did have a conflict with my .hgignore file (which was different between my bb and dev).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have files that need to be changed on deployment then they shouldn't be in Mercurial or they should be under a non-live name.  Otherwise, when you pull it will get overwritten by what's in Mercurial.

You could have separate configurations on separate branches and merge core changes from "trunk" but you have to be careful with this and it may be more work that it's worth.  I have a development environment where do this.  I merge my open-source branch to my proprietary branch. I just have to be careful to do the merge in the right direction.